# Elasticsearch GetResponse.getField throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, elasticsearch

For that code:

```
GetResponse response = client.prepareGet("people","Doe","OlU1D2sBV_LsgiLLjxMs").get();
```

response's value is:

```
{"_index":"people","_type":"Doe","_id":"OlU1D2sBV_LsgiLLjxMs",
"_version":1,"_seq_no":1,"_primary_term":1,"found":true,"_source":
{"fullName":"Test","dateOfBirth2":"2019-05-31T18:44:58.086Z","age":"10"}}
```

So why when I do:

```
String age = (String) response.getField("age").getValue();
```

it throws a NullPointerException?

I mean, I know what a NullPointerException is, but why doesn't it find the "age" if it exists in the results?

I took the code from the example: [Guide to Elasticsearch in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/elasticsearch-java), section 4.3 Retrieving and Deleting Documents.

Comment: You should get the field's value through getSourceAsMap.get("age");

Comment: @ByronVoorbach great it's working now! Please write it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Done, thanks! happy coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the field's value you should use response.getSourceAsMap("age"); Then it will work.

Happy coding!